What is the probability that a penalty shoot-out in soccer will end with a difference of 1, 2 or 3 goals?
I already have an answer to this question, but I do not know, if it is correct and I do not find an answer in the www.
There are up to 10 shots. So, I simply created all $2^{10}$ posibilities from 0 goals over the ten posibilities of exactly 1 goal (it could be the first, second, ... or last shot that goals) to 10 goals.
If one team cannot catch up the other, the shoot-out ends immediately. So, a difference of 4 or 5 is never possible, because after e. g. 6 shots and 3:0 the game ends, because team 2 has only 2 shots left and can therefore not win. If the score is drawn after 10 shots, the game will end with a difference of 1.
That's the whole logic. I wrote a C# program for this and get a result. But you never know if you have taken everything into account. If you want to know the answer, checkout this fiddle, but maybe you want to try yourselves first.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The scenario with the end after $6$ shots incredibly happened in the current european soccer championship in Germany.

The logic is correct , so if you programmed it correctly , it should correctly do the job.

What do you assume for the probability that a shot gets on target ? A constant probability $p$ ?

An end after 6 shots only happens if goal-nogoal > goal-nogoal > goal-nogoal or vice versa. This is a probability of $2/1024=0.2$%.

Hm, I think the probability that a shot gets on target is not relevant unless it is not 1 or 0, because then all 1024 possibilities are equally likely. But yes, it must be constant and equal for both teams.

Not at all, we have the Laplacian case ONLY if $p=\frac{1}{2}$ , but this is very unrealistic in pratice. I would rather assume something like $p=\frac{5}{6}$ for a more or less realistic model.

Oha, I think you are right. 10x "no goal" is not as likely as 10x "goal" unless $p=\frac{1}{2}$.

@Flippowitsch That calculation for probability of ending in 6 shots should be 2/64 = 3.125%. There are only 2^6 possible ways the first 6 shots could go, not 2^10.

You're right! Thanks for the correction.

I get the same result
1: 0.546875
2: 0.351562
3: 0.101562

Let the success probabilities of the teams be $p_1$ and $p_2$ (I guess these we're assumed to be $\frac{1}{2}$). And let there be maximum of $N$ shots ($N=10$). Call the situation that one team cannot catch up the other as game over.
I used the following dynamic approach. Consider the states $(n, k)$ where $n$ is the total number of shots taken and $k$ is the difference of the scores. We start from the state $(0, 0)$ and consider all the possible paths to the states $(N, k)$ and multiply the probabilities along the paths and sum all paths so we get the results. This can be done round by round dynamically so it's efficient.

If $n$ is even, it's team 1's turn.

If $(n,k)$ is not game over, it produces $(n+1, k+1)$ with probability $p_1$ and $(n+1, k)$ with probability $1-p_1$.
If it is game over, then $(n,k)$ just produces $(n+1, k)$ with probability $1$.

Game over is checked by $|k|>M-j$, where $M=\frac{N}{2}$ and $j = \frac{n}{2}$. (Note: the game over check stays satisfied as $n$ increases so we can do it like this, otherwise maybe introduce a new state for the "game over with $k$" so we know to stay in it if we're in it.)
If $n$ is odd, it's team 2's turn and things go similarly but now we subtract one from $k$ with probability $p_2$ and stay the same with probability $1-p_2$.
Call the end result $d(k)$.
To get the desired probabilities, for $1$ it is $d(-1)+d(0)+d(1)$ (as tie was considered as difference of $1$) and for $k>1$ it is $d(-k)+d(k)$.
Python code
Update
If we take $p=p_1=p_2$ as variable and run the code (now using Sage, in order to handle polynomials) we get the following formulas
1:
$$
-56 p^{10} + 336 p^{9} - 886 p^{8} + 1364 p^{7} - 1360 p^{6} + 916 p^{5} - 418 p^{4} + 124 p^{3} - 20 p^{2} + 1
$$
2:
$$
56 p^{10} - 336 p^{9} + 892 p^{8} - 1394 p^{7} + 1419 p^{6} - 976 p^{5} + 451 p^{4} - 132 p^{3} + 20 p^{2}
$$
3:
$$-6 p^{8} + 30 p^{7} - 59 p^{6} + 60 p^{5} - 33 p^{4} + 8 p^{3}
$$
graphs at Desmos

Great answer and great picture! How do you make the picture?

In Desmos, here's the link in fact: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x2ugqf2oai

Nice! I played with the probabilities $p_1=p_2$ and observed, that there are maxima and minima. I changed your code slightly to loop over the function and start with $p_1=p_2=0.01$ with step $0.01$ and end at $p_1=p_2=0.99$. Please see here. Unfortunately, I cannot add the corresponding Excel chart in this comment.

Yes, that looks interesting! I put them in Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a7lqfsxyel . Maybe a closed formula in terms of $p$ could be derived, since this could also be written as a matrix multiplication, but the matrix changes step to step (time inhomogenous Markov Chain). The first $5$ steps it's the same,  but then the possibilities for game over appear...

Or actually we can just use that dynamic method but keep the result as polynomial of $p$. Edited that to the answer. Btw, I had the points in the previous Desmos graph off by one step (in my previous comment).

Thanks for that. I observed another interesting fact: I wanted to test your original code for plausibility and changed the goal probabilities to $p_1=0.8$ and $p_2=0.2$. Then I swapped them to $p_1=0.2$ and $p_2=0.8$. I expected the exactly same result, but the result is different. Can this be correct?

I think so, since there's the asymmetry of team 1 going first. The transition graph isn't symmetric about the x-axis. Even if we have $p_2 = 1-p_1$ so that if we mirror the graph and complete the transitions, then the vertical transitions have different probabilities alternately, so I guess that makes the asymmetry(?). If we take both $p_1$ and $p_2$ as variables we have these formulas: https://www.desmos.com/3d/g69meu2rwq

This 3D plot is pretty cool. When you follow the xy-angle bisector, you can see exactly the plots we saw, when we varied $p_1=p_2$ from $0.01$ to $0.99$. The assymetry you describe is also clearly visible: The blue and the purple surfaces are not even similar. Of course, the assymetry is there, because the 3D plot is based on the Python code and if there is an error in the code, there must be an error in the plot. But I think you are right and the code is correct and there is really an assymetry. Thanks again!

@Flippowitsch Try the 4 shot short game.  The AbAbAxxx (+3) case of "ahead by 3" corresponds to the bAbAbAxx(+3) bAbABAxx (+2) cases with reversed first player.
